# File.getFreeSpace() Not returning correct value

Tags: java, unc

I use `file.GetFreeSpace()` from Java's File class in my application to make sure that there is enough room before transferring files.  The path is a unc path that currently has ~5TB of free space on it.  However when the above code is ran, the amount of space returned is only 713998336 Bytes (~680MB).

I mapped the application to use a different unc path that had in between 100MB and a little over 1GB free  (I was adding/removing files to test) and the application reported the correct amount of free space there.

UPDATE: Through much debugging, I have found the issue. 
The unc path similar to this: `\\domain6\test\Scratch_Folder\` where Scratch_Folder is a DFS namespace with ~5TB of free space.  However when `file.getFreeSpace` executes, it is returning the free space for `\\domain6\test\` which only has 670MB.  Why would this happen?

Comment: Is `getTotalSpace` working properly (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace%28%29)?

Comment: Looks like you are suffering from a 32-bit overflow. e.g. 5 TB - 4.2 billion is about 0.7 TB.

Comment: @Vlad - getTotalSpace only reports `16096837632` (~15GB), where the total size is actually 5.69TB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! Java was returning the amount of free space in the root of the DFS, not the actual folder of the DFS (the Scratch_Folder was showing up as a shortcut).  I found a different, more direct path to the folder that didn't contain the shortcut, pointed the application there instead and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in your JVM. This feature is new to Java 6, can you try Java 6 update 25. When I run this for a UNC path with 9 TB free, I see 9 TB.