# Java accessing files in a DFS filesystem via URL

Tags: java, microsoft-distributed-file-system

We are testing a system in our development environment where we are moving file system to DFS leaves.  Everything is working fine except for when images are trying to be accessed via a URL instead of a UNC path (For previewing images - they show up as broken links).  We believe it's a deep-rooted configuration issue somewhere on the development servers and not related to the change in the file system setup as the image previews work when I change it to point to the images via UNC path instead of the URL, but we have run into odd problems with Java and DFS systems in the past ( [File.getFreeSpace() Not returning correct value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281580/file-getfreespace-not-returning-correct-value)) so I was wondering if there was any sort of documentation for Java saying that accessing a file through DFS via a URL should not be an issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is your URL properly formatted for the DFS path? As far as I have seen you shouldn't have an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue was an IIS setting, so there is no issue with accessing a DFS filesystem via URL in Java :)